# how to make a basic menu using kivy

Tags: python, menu, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to make a simple menu with buttons and labels using Kivy, but I cannot make the menu display

The menu should display a label and 4 buttons all seperated with a space, but instead all that is being outputted is a black screen.
**This is the python code:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    pass

class IrishSnapsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainMenu(padding=50)

root=IrishSnapsApp()

root.run()
```

**# And then this is the Kv file named IrishSnaps.kv:**

```
<MainMenu>:
    
    orientation:'vertical'

    Label:
        text: 'Irish Snaps'
        size_hint: 1, 0.2
        font_size: 30
    Button:
        id: Singleplayer
        text: 'Singleplayer'
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        font_size: 24
        background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
        font_size: 24
        background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
    Button:
        id: Multiplayer
        text: 'Multiplayer'
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        font_size: 2
        background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
        font_size: 24
        background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
    Button:
        id: Statistics
        text: 'Statistics'
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        font_size: 24
        background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,1)
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
        font_size: 24
        background_color: (0.811,0.745,0.549,0)
    Button:
        id: Closegame
        text: 'Close game'
        size_hint: 0.5, 0.2
        pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5}
```

Comment: Try changing the name of your `kv` file from `IrishSnaps.kv` to `irishsnaps.kv` (No caps).

Comment: @JohnAnderson I tried this, but it does not work, it still outputs just a white screen

Comment: Try  changing `root.run` to `root.run()`

Comment: @JohnAnderson This time it produces an error as follows:                                   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Many indentation errors in your `kv` file.

Comment: I believe now I have corrected the indentation errors, making each indentation 4 spaces, but it now says in line 03 there is invalid data after declaration

Comment: Cannot reproduce that error.

Comment: I re-wrote the code and it now outputs the buttons, so thank you for your help.